# how to call method in jstl jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

This question can be duplicate and have lots of answers on StackOverflow.

But I still did not get what is the issue in my code.

There is an object stored in session that is cmdResponse of type MessageResponse class

This is how I am getting from session

#### Command Response :

```
<%
    Object cmdResponse = session.getAttribute("cmdResponse");
    MessageResponse messageResponse = (MessageResponse) cmdResponse;
%>
```

There is getMessage() method that is getter method. Here is the code of MessageResponse class

```
public class MessageResponse extends Response {
    String message;

public MessageResponse() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MessageResponse(String command, String message) {
    super(command);
    this.message = message;
}


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

}
```

and this is how I am trying to render

```
<c:out value="${messageResponse.getMessage()}" />
```

but above line renders nothing and no error on the server. What can be the issue ?

Comment: duplicate but what is the issue in this ? i did the same

Comment: What duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the `messageResponse` variable as an attribute to the `request`, if you want to make it accessible from EL.

```
request.setAttribute("messageResponse", messageResponse);
```

Or you can use

```
<c:out value="${cmdResponse.getMessage()}" />
```

as EL tries the `session` when it does not find the name in `request`.

Last, but not least, `<c:out value="${messageResponse.message}" />` (or `<c:out value="${cmdResponse.message}" />` should be enough, EL calls the appropriate getter oh its own.